# dataframe vectorization

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

In my code below, I created a DataFrame df with sample data containing value, as well as timestamps. Additionally, I've added a new column 'value_timespan' and initialized it with -1. Then, I iterate through the DataFrame to calculate the time span between consecutive positive values in the 'value' column. 
Two things to note,
first is that even if there are multiple consecutive positive values, only the time difference of successive positive values forming pairs will be calculated, and the subsequent positive values not forming a pair will not be calculated. (see examples below)
second is that there can be any number of zeros between consecutive positive values.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Sample data
data = {    
    'datetime': [
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 0, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 5, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 10, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 15, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 20, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 25, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 30, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 35, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 40, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 45, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 50, 0),
    ],
    'value': [1,  3, 4, 2, -1, 1, 0, 2, -3, 0, -3],                   
}

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['value_timespan'] = -1
# Initialize variables to keep track of the last positive value and its timestamp
last_positive_value = None
last_positive_timestamp = None
# Iterate through the DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['value'] > 0:
        if last_positive_value is not None:
            # Calculate the time span between the current positive value and the last positive value
            time_difference = (row['datetime'] - last_positive_timestamp).total_seconds()
            df.at[index, 'value_timespan'] = time_difference
            last_positive_value = None
            last_positive_timestamp = None
        else:
            last_positive_value = row['value']
            last_positive_timestamp = row['datetime']
    if row['value'] < 0:
        last_positive_value = None
        last_positive_timestamp = None        
print(df)
```

which prints out results like below, (1, 3), (4, 2), (1, 2) are considered pairs

```
            datetime        | value | value_timespan
        --------------------------------------------
    0   2023-11-11 08:00:00 |   1   | -1
    1   2023-11-11 08:05:00 |   3   | 300
    2   2023-11-11 08:10:00 |   4   | -1
    3   2023-11-11 08:15:00 |   2   | 300
    4   2023-11-11 08:20:00 |  -1   | -1
    5   2023-11-11 08:25:00 |   1   | -1
    6   2023-11-11 08:30:00 |   0   | -1
    7   2023-11-11 08:35:00 |   2   | 600
    8   2023-11-11 08:40:00 |  -3   | -1
    9   2023-11-11 08:45:00 |   0   | -1
    10  2023-11-11 08:50:00 |  -3   | -1
```

Now, I'd like to vectorize my code.
How can I do this correctly?

**UPDATE 2023/12/07**
For example, for 'value': [1,  3, 1, -2, -1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, -3],
the correct results are, because (1, 3), (1, 3) forms a pair

```
            datetime    | value | timespan
-----------------------------------------
0   2023-11-11 08:00:00 |  1    | -1.0
1   2023-11-11 08:05:00 |  3    | 300.0
2   2023-11-11 08:10:00 |  1    | -1.0
3   2023-11-11 08:15:00 | -2    | -1.0
4   2023-11-11 08:20:00 | -1    | -1.0
5   2023-11-11 08:25:00 |  1    | -1.0
6   2023-11-11 08:30:00 |  0    | -1.0
7   2023-11-11 08:35:00 |  0    | -1.0
8   2023-11-11 08:40:00 |  3    | 900.0
9   2023-11-11 08:45:00 |  0    | -1.0
10  2023-11-11 08:50:00 | -3    | -1.0
```

hope my requirements are clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** new version, fully vectorized using just `numpy`: **26 ms for 1 million rows**.

#### A vectorized solution

Terse and fast, here it is. I will provide explanations below.

```py
def get_timespan(df):
    v = df['value'].to_numpy()
    g = (v < 0).cumsum()
    ipos = np.flatnonzero(v > 0)
    gpx = np.r_[-1, g[ipos]]
    z = gpx[1:] == gpx[:-1]
    chg = np.flatnonzero(~z)
    z[chg[1:]] |= (np.diff(chg) % 2) == 0
    ix = np.flatnonzero(np.bitwise_xor.accumulate(z))
    t = df.iloc[ipos]['t'].to_numpy()
    ts = np.full(len(v), -1)  # or use -1.0 if a float output is desired
    ts[ipos[ix]] = (t[ix] - t[ix - 1]) // 1e9
    return ts
```

#### Simplified setups

To test this, we consider a few setups: `op1` is the first example provided by the OP, `op2` the second one. Then, `gen(n)` generates arbitrarily large test `df`.

```py
def op(value):
    t = pd.date_range('2023-11-11 08:00:00', freq='5min', periods=len(value))
    return pd.DataFrame({'t': t, 'value': value})

op1 = op([1,  3, 4, 2, -1, 1, 0, 2, -3, 0, -3])
op2 = op([1, 3, 1, -2, -1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, -3])

def gen(n):
    np.random.seed(0)
    return op(np.random.randint(-10, 100, n))
```

#### Tests

```py
>>> get_timespan(op1)
array([ -1, 300,  -1, 300,  -1,  -1,  -1, 600,  -1,  -1,  -1])

>>> get_timespan(op2)
array([ -1, 300,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1, 900,  -1,  -1])

# or, to see it as a column of df:
>>> op1.assign(timespan=get_timespan(op1))
                     t  value  timespan
0  2023-11-11 08:00:00      1        -1
1  2023-11-11 08:05:00      3       300
2  2023-11-11 08:10:00      4        -1
3  2023-11-11 08:15:00      2       300
4  2023-11-11 08:20:00     -1        -1
5  2023-11-11 08:25:00      1        -1
6  2023-11-11 08:30:00      0        -1
7  2023-11-11 08:35:00      2       600
8  2023-11-11 08:40:00     -3        -1
9  2023-11-11 08:45:00      0        -1
10 2023-11-11 08:50:00     -3        -1
```

#### Speed

```py
df = gen(1_000_000)

%timeit get_timespan(df)
25.8 ms ± 118 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

#### (Detailed) explanation

The first part is fairly customary: we establish groups of consecutive non-negative values (which group the negative values themselves fall into doesn't matter). We'll use `op1` for example:

```py
df = op1
v = df['value'].to_numpy()
g = (v < 0).cumsum()
>>> np.c_[v, g].T
array([[ 1,  3,  4,  2, -1,  1,  0,  2, -3,  0, -3],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  3]])
```

Notice how the first four values are together in group 1, the next four in group 2 (starting with -1), etc.

The next piece is to figure which of these values are strictly positive. To visualize indices, we use a little helper function `rix`  that produces `1` at the index and `0` everywhere else (given an example full size vector):

```py
def rix(ix, v):
    a = np.zeros_like(v)
    a[ix] = 1
    return a
```

With this:

```py
ipos = np.flatnonzero(v > 0)  # 0,1,2,3,5,7
>>> np.c_[v, g, rix(ipos, v)].T
array([[ 1,  3,  4,  2, -1,  1,  0,  2, -3,  0, -3],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  3],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0]])
```

From here, we can focus on `gp = g[ipos]`, the group values where `v` is positive.

Now, a tricky part. We need to find every odd index of `ipos` but *within each group*. It is every other `ipos`, but sometimes we must skip one (where a group has changed, we cannot pick the first one).

To illustrate the problem, imagine that we have:

```py
gp = np.array([0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2])
```

In that case, we'd like to find the second `0` (index 1), the second `1` (index 3), and the second and fourth `2` (indices 6,8).

To do that, we devise a mask, the `xor`-accumulation of which will be `1` only at the indices of interest.

That mask, `z`, is initially `True` for all elements of `gp` except the first one in a group. To facilitate things, we add a sentinel `-1` at the beginning:

```py
gpx = np.r_[-1, gp]
z = gpx[1:] == gpx[:-1]
>>> np.c_[gp, z].T
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

We also track the index where `gp` changes:

```py
chg = np.flatnonzero(~z)
>>> chg
array([0, 2, 5])
```

Now, to correct `z`, we set to `1` the first place in a group where the previous group had an even length. Then, we `xor`-accumulate those bits:

```py
z[chg[1:]] |= (np.diff(chg) % 2) == 0
m = np.bitwise_xor.accumulate(z)
>>> np.c_[gp, z, m].T
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

and there you have it, the ones in `m` are the indices we want. So, in summary:

```py
ix = np.flatnonzero(np.bitwise_xor.accumulate(z))
>>> ix
array([1, 3, 6, 8])
```

Back to the `op1` example, `ix` is `[1, 3, 5]` (relative to `ipos`).

Finally, the timespan at these locations is simply `t[ix] - t[ix - 1]` (where `t` is `df.iloc[ipos]['t']`).

Comment: Your ingenious, densely-coded answer highlights some interesting points for me: 1. In my answer just the `df.mask` line alone is several times slower than your whole code. 2. Your first (now deleted) answer showed that `pd.groupby` is so very slow which I did not fully appreciate 3. If you want to be **really** fast with DFs then you have to use Numpy directly avoiding even Pandas vectorized functions and accept losing the 'obviousness' of Pandas code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the code can be fully vectorized because of the successive pair treatment and progressive look-back required - which is why you used the last_ values in your own code. Firstly note that `itertuples` is faster than `iterrows` because a Pandas Series is not formed from each row. But it is better to do only essential looping over an extracted Series than over the DF rows. The code below demonstrates that. This processes 1M rows of your data in about 0.5s which I guess will be adequate in a stand-alone application.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

CHANGE = 1
NOCHANGE = -1
MAYBE = 0

# Sample data
data = {    
    'datetime': [
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 0, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 5, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 10, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 15, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 20, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 25, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 30, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 35, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 40, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 45, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 50, 0),
    ],
   'value': [1,  3, 4, 2, -1, 1, 0, 2, -3, 0, -3]
#  'value': [1, 3, 1, -2, -1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, -3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# form working df with only non-zero 'value' using copy to maintain index for later re-insertion
df2 = df[df['value'].ne(0)].copy()

#create temp column and mark rows with negative values as NOCHANGE and others as MAYBE
df2['markers'] = NOCHANGE
df2['markers'] = df2['markers'].mask(df2['value'].gt(0), MAYBE)

#loop through df column and mark values to be changed with CHANGE, others with NOCHANGE
prev = CHANGE
res = []        #temp store for modified marks
for entry in df2['markers']:
    if entry == NOCHANGE:
        res.append(NOCHANGE)
        prev = NOCHANGE
    elif entry == MAYBE and prev == MAYBE:
        res.append(CHANGE)
        prev = CHANGE
    else:
        res.append(NOCHANGE)
        prev = MAYBE
df2['markers'] = res

#add timespan to rows marked with CHANGE
df2['markers'] = df2['markers'].mask(df2['markers'].eq(CHANGE), (df2['datetime']-df2['datetime'].shift(1)).dt.total_seconds())

#merge timespan results back into original DF using indices then fill rows missing from DF2 (value 0) with -1
df['timespan'] = df2['markers']
df['timespan'] = df['timespan'].fillna(NOCHANGE).astype(int)

print(df)
```

which gives:

```
              datetime  value  timespan
0  2023-11-11 08:00:00      1        -1
1  2023-11-11 08:05:00      3       300
2  2023-11-11 08:10:00      4        -1
3  2023-11-11 08:15:00      2       300
4  2023-11-11 08:20:00     -1        -1
5  2023-11-11 08:25:00      1        -1
6  2023-11-11 08:30:00      0        -1
7  2023-11-11 08:35:00      2       600
8  2023-11-11 08:40:00     -3        -1
9  2023-11-11 08:45:00      0        -1
10 2023-11-11 08:50:00     -3        -1
```

Comment: the code can be fully vectorized.